# How do I install software in debian if I cannot use the network and the system doesn't recognize the iso?

Tags: linux, debian, installation

I am running Debian 10.5.0. I have installed debian using netbootin and a flash drive.

I am now trying to install various packages and programs which are on the iso. When I try a command like:

```
sudo apt-get install -y konsole
```

I receive the following request:

```
Media Change: Please insert the disc labeled
    'Debian GNU/linux 10.5.0 _[...]'
in the drive '/media/cdrom' and press [Enter]
```

I have tried copying the debian install iso to a local folder, and then copying it into the media/cdrom file. This fails. I have also tried using the mount command, along the lines of:

```
sudo mount -o loop /path_to_my_iso/iso_name.iso /media/cdrom
```

I have also tried simply plugging in the install iso. This also does not work.

I would like to download packages from the internet, but the debian release does not have drivers for my laptop's wireless card (and, indeed, does not seem to recognize that there is a wireless card at all), thus making the process even more of a headache.

This leads me to wonder 2 things: (1) academically, why do modern systems presume the use of CDs at all, given that most systems don't come with optical drives anymore, and (2) how do I get debian to recognize my ISO and install the software/packages from it?

Comment: Buy a USB-to-ethernet adapter if your laptop doesn't have an ethernet connector. It's not expensive, and it can save your ass at times.

Answer (score 0):

A driver for the particular WiFi adapter on your PC is apparently missing. You'll need to find the make and model of the adapter from your PC user guide or from the web, and then download (via Ethernet or another PC) that particular driver and install it *per* directions specific to that driver.

For example, for the Realtek r8168 adapter, [see Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/kernel/r8168-dkms).

Once you have WiFi working, you can easily download and install software from Debian or the software vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Debian is a project that strictly adheres to FOSS guidelines.  It does not include any software that is not open source, and this includes the firmware that is needed to make a lot of Wifi hardware work--because the device manufactuers don't release the source code to this firmware.

The full Debian OS is about [16 DVDs](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/jigdo-dvd/) and needs to be downloaded using a tool called `jigdo` from an existing Debian system - this contains every single package available. If you actually download and burn all of these and install from them, `apt` will prompt you for discs as needed, but can still check the Internet for updates.

The complete opposite end of this is the `netinst` images which only have enough of Debian for you to run `apt` and download everything else you need from mirrors.

Because of all that above, Debian will reference CDs/DVDs when installing unless you use a netinst image.  It sounds like you downloaded the first DVD or CD in a set, and that's supported--the first disc in a set has everything needed to get a basic system up and running, but still doesn't include the non-free firmware and obviously won't include all packages.

There are "unofficial" netinst installers that have the non-free firmware included.  You should download and use one of those.  Look [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/).